# Como abrir una nueva pagina php

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo una duda, estoy trabajando en wordpress y he creado un snippet para extraer datos de una url con datos xlm. Lo que nose es como hacer para que cuando pinche en la etiqueta
`<a>a</a>` me abra una nueva pagina. Aqui os paso el código.

```
add_shortcode( 'lista_coches', 'lista_coche' );

function lista_coche(){
        // URL DE ACCESO AL XML
    $url = "https://carspark.dealerk.es/myPortalXML/index?myPortalXMLkey=0fc90c15-32eb-40a5-9b21-f13ec1a6b77e";

    // Carga de Archivo XML
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    // Vamos a recorrer el array de cars
    $cars = $xml->car;
    foreach ($cars as $car) {
        

        $car_name = (string) $car -> subTitle;
        $car_ano = (string) $car -> registrationDate;
        $car_descripcion = (string) $car -> description;
        $car_km = (string) $car -> km;
        $car_carroceria = (string) $car -> bodyType;
        $car_cambio = (string) $car -> gear -> gearType;
        $car_puertas = (string) $car -> doors;
        $car_asientos = (string) $car -> seats;
        $car_cilindrada= (string) $car ->cc;
        $car_caballos = (string) $car -> hp;
        $car_color = (string) $car -> exterior -> color;
        $car_combustible = (string) $car -> fuelType;
        $car_precioContado = (string) $car -> prices -> priceB2c;
        $car_precioFinanciado = (string) $car -> prices -> financedPrice;
        $car_portada = (string) $car -> images -> image;
        
    
     

         
        echo '
        
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#" class="open-popup card-a">
                
                    <img src="'.$car_portada.'" alt="imagen_coche">
                
                <div class="card-info">
                    <h1>'.$car_name.'</h1>
                    <p class="descripcion"><span>'.$car_combustible.'</span>|<span>'.$car_ano.'</span>|<span>'.$car_km.'km</span>|<span>'.$car_caballos.'cv</span></p>
                    <div class="card-precio">
                        <div class="contado"><p>Precio al contado</p><h3>'.number_format($car_precioContado).'€</h3></div>
                        <div class ="financiado"><p>Precio financiado</p><h3>'.number_format($car_precioFinanciado).'€</h3></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div hidden>
           <h1>Coche</h1>
        </div>
        ';
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En caso de duda, siempre cae bien leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) de sitios confiables.

> ### target
>
> Where to display the linked URL, as the name for a browsing context (a tab, window, or ). The following keywords have special meanings for where to load the URL:
>
> `_self`: the current browsing context. (Default)
>
> `_blank`: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.
>
> `_parent`: the parent browsing context of the current one. If no parent, behaves as _self.
>
> `_top`: the topmost browsing context (the "highest" context that's an ancestor of the current one). If no ancestors, behaves as _self.

Como quien dice, `target='_blank'` abre en una nueva ventana/pesataña según le parezca a tu navegador.